# How to cast Hibernate QueryList to custom class

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

I got the result from Hibernate HQL `query.list()`. So, the return are all in `Object[]`. The fields of each item of the array are also in `Object[]`. The contents are correct.

So, is there anyway to cast it to a custom java object?

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking...

Comment: Show us your query and entity classes

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with `.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(YourClass.class))`

Each field should be mapped with projection, like :

```
.setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("propertyName"), "alias")
    //... other properties
)
```

Look [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.hibernate.transform.Transformers) for many examples

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast using [TypedQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager; 

public List<Employee> findEmployees() {
     TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e", Employee.class);
     return query.getResultList();
}
```

Moreover, this is `JPA` API, and you can use it along with `Hibernate` or other `JPA` provider.